# ASP.NET MVC + EF: storing configurations and settings that dont fit in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, configuration, settings

What is the best way to store (and later modify from the application itself) some variables that dont fit in the database?

For example: "`string systemEmail`" that is used to send emails when there are problems in the system.

Certainly using a table in the database for that is not ok, because I would have to use 1 registry in that table (eg. `SystemConfigurations.First().SystemEmail`)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingName"] = settingValue

These are stored in web.config